# Rails - Back button duplicating elements

Tags: javascript, html

I've come across an issue where a user can go to a certain page, go to a new page, press the chrome back button (happens with all major browsers) and some elements will be duplicated.

The elements in question come from JavaScript within a partial view I am rendering as part of that page.

I have seen some people having this issue while using turbolinks, however I don't have that installed so I am not sure what is causing this issue.

I have tried putting bindings in Chrome dev console on the JavaScript that is run to create these elements, however on Chrome back button press, it doesn't trigger, so I'm not sure why they are being duplicated.

Below is what I'm doing to create the elements that are being duplicated:

```
theFieldset = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[0];
editForm = document.getElementById("edit_pattern");
theFieldset.innerHTML += "<div class='form-group control-group belongs_to_association_type pattern_field ' id='pattern_html_block_id_field'><label class='col-sm-2 control-label' for='pattern_pattern_html_block'>Attach template</label><div class='controls col-sm-10' data-children-count='2'><select data-filteringselect='true' placeholder='Search' name='email[pattern_id]' id='pattern_pattern_html_block' style='display: none;'><option value=''></option></select><span class='help-block'>Optional. </span></div></div><div class='form-group control-group belongs_to_association_type pattern_field ' id='pattern_pattern_field' style='display:none'><label class='col-sm-2 control-label' for='currentTemplate'>Current template</label><div class='controls col-sm-10' data-children-count='2'></div><br><label class='col-sm-2 control-label' for='pattern_pattern_html_block'>Attach template</label><div class='controls col-sm-10' data-children-count='2'></div></div>";
```

Edit: Neither turbolinks nor hotwire is installed. Have been unsuccessful in trying to individually create elements and adding them to the fieldset rather than adding in bulk via innerHTML or insertAdjacentHTML.

Comment: You are most likely using Turbolinks and your code is not idempotent https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#making-transformations-idempotent. You can simply check if you already have that content before adding it. (one extra tip, don't use `innertHTML +=`, use `insertAdjacentHTML` to preserve bindings)

Comment: @arieljuod Thanks for the reply. I've included your tip, and am currently looking at making it idempotent. This is to say that I should check for current elements before running the JavaScript in that partial, correct? The issue with that is, I've already tried that and I am unable to. For instance, I check if one of the labels exists, if not, run the JS, else skip it all. There is still double the elements. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @arieljuod Also, sorry but if I don't have Turbolinks in the gemfile how could I be using it? I think this might be a seperate issue to turbolinks, but I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: If you don't have Turbolinks anywhere then I'm not sure what's the issue, maybe you have something that's doing a similar job (faking pages navigation using ajax instead the browser doing a normal http request), maybe you are using hotwire? if the javascript code is still running twice, put a `debugger` call and debug it using chrome's dev tools to check if your condition is correct

Comment: About the debugger, I tried to set on in the chrome dev tools at the beginning of the JavaScript. When going to a new page, and pressing the back button, that binding is not stopping any execution (meaning the js is not actually being run?). So yeah pretty stuck with this. Will have a look if there are any ajax calls but I can't think of any that I'm aware of. - Also, hotwire is not being used either.

Comment: @DanielLawton please share [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

I would use `theFieldSet.appendChild(div)` instead of `fieldSet.innerHTML` here is an example of the code!

```js
var theFieldset = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[0];
var editForm = document.getElementById("edit_pattern");
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'form-group control-group belongs_to_association_type pattern_field ';
div.id='pattern_html_block_id_field';
var label = document.createElement('label');
label.className = 'col-sm-2 control-label';
label.id = 'theLabel';

var div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.className = 'controls col-sm-10';
div2.id = 'div_2';
var selectE = document.createElement('select');
selectE.id = 'pattern_pattern_html_block';
var option = document.createElement('option');
option.value = '';
var spanE = document.createElement('span');
spanE.className = 'help-block';
var div3 = document.createElement('div');
div3.className = 'form-group control-group belongs_to_association_type pattern_field ';
div3.id = 'pattern_pattern_field';
var labelEL = document.createElement('label');
labelEL.className = 'col-sm-2 control-label';
labelEL.id = 'labelElement2';
var div4 = document.createElement('div');
div4.id = 'DivEl4'
div4.className = 'controls col-sm-10'
var breakPoint_ = document.createElement('br');
breakPoint_.id = 'breakPoint';
var label_el2 = document.createElement('label')
label_el2.id = 'LabelEl3';
label_el2.className = 'col-sm-2 control-label';
var div5 = document.createElement('div')
div5.className = 'controls col-sm-10';
div5.id = 'DivEl5';

div[0].appendChild(label);
div2[0].appendChild(selectE);
selectE[0].appendChild(option);
spanE[0].appendChild(div2);
document.getElementByTagName("[div]'s parent")[0].appendChild(div3);
div2[0].appendChild(span);
div3[0].appendChild(labelEL);
div3[0].appendChild(breakPoint_);
div3[0].appendChild(label_el2);
div3[0].appendChild(div5

document.getElementById('LabelEl3').attr('for','pattern_pattern_html_block');
document.getElementById('LabelEl3').text('Attach template');
document.getElementById('DivEl5').attr('data-children-count','2');
document.getElementById('DivEl4').attr('data-children-count','2');
document.getElementById('labelElement2').attr('for','currentTemplate');
document.getElementById('labelElement2').text('Current template');
document.getElementById('pattern_pattern_field').css('display','none');
document.getElementsByClassName('help-block').text('Optional. ');
document.getElementById('select_element').attr('name','email[pettern_id]');
document.getElementById('pattern_pattern_html_block').attr('placeholder','Search');
document.getElementById('pattern_pattern_html_block').css('display', 'none');
document.getElementById('theLabel').attr('for','pattern_pattern_html_block');
document.getElementById('theLabel').text('Attach template');
document.getElementById('div_2').attr('data-children-count','2');
```

I hope this works I spent a long time on it I know it is messy but it should work

Comment: What have you done.

Comment: Lol I don't know I couldn't figure out anything

Comment: Sorry if this didn't help :( I really didn't think of anything

Comment: @Ryan'sWorld I appreciate you taking the time but the elements are still duplicated when browsing to a new web page and pressing the back button on the browser.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help